# What's wrong with my proof that $m^{\aleph_0} = n^{\aleph_0}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

What's wrong with my proof that $m^{\aleph_0} = n^{\aleph_0}$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Where $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.

First, we observe that $f(x) = tan(x)$ defines a bijective correspondence between $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Then, $g(x) = \pi x - \frac{pi}{2}x$ defines a bijective correspondence between $(\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(0,1)$.

So $g(f(x))$ defines a bijective correspondence between $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(0,1)$

Thus the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is the same as the cardinality of $(0,1)$.

Now, think of the points in $(0,1)$ as decimal numbers reduced modulo $2$. Thus the set $(0,1)$ is in bijective correspondence with all sequences of $0$ and $1$. We can now see that the cardinality of $(0,1)$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Now, think of the points in $(0,1)$ as decimal numbers reduced modulo $3$. Thus the set $(0,1)$ is in bijective correspondence with all sequences of $0,1$ and $2$. We can now see that the cardinality of $(0,1)$ is $3^{\aleph_0}$

Now, think of the points in $(0,1)$ as decimal numbers reduced modulo $n$. Thus the set $(0,1)$ is in bijective correspondence with all sequences of $0,1,2,....,$ and $n$.We can now see that the cardinality of $(0,1)$ is $n^{\aleph_0}$

My claim follows

Comment: Isn't $n=1$ a special case?

Comment: This proof is pretty good, if overly wordy.  Of course you must say $m,n \ge 2$ in your formulation.  That bijection between $(0,1)$ and binary expansions is almost (but not completely) bijective.  Same for other bases.

Comment: A few small things: (1) You want to throw $||$ around those or something similar, because the _sets_ aren't equal, but they're bijective. (2) You don't need the correspondence between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$; as soon as you show that both $m^{\aleph_0}$ and $n^{\aleph_0}$ both biject to (0,1) you're done without even knowing the cardinality of the latter. And (3) as noted by GEdgar, you don't exactly have a bijection; there are some values $r\in(0,1)$ with multiple sequences from $n^{\aleph_0}$ mapping to them under your mapping. This is easily repairable, but it still requires repair.

Comment: For any $m,n≤\aleph_0$ we have $$2^{\aleph_0}≤m^{\aleph_0}≤\left (2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}≤2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0}$$

Comment: There are two special cases $n = 1$ and $n = 0$ which you ignored. Other than that, this is pretty close to being a proof, except that you ignore that some numbers have multiple decimal representations. An easier proof is to note that for all $n \geq 1$, we have $(2^n)^{\aleph_0} = 2^{n \cdot \aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. So given any $k \geq 2$, we have $2^{\aleph_0} \leq k^{\aleph_0} \leq (2^k)^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to assume $n\not=1$. More substantively, there is a slight issue around passing from $(0,1)$ to $m^\mathbb{N}$ since in general a number in $(0,1)$ may have multiple base-$n$ expansions. *(There's also the issue that you really want $[0,1]$ - think about the sequences $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{n-1}$ in base $n$, respectively - but meh.)* Basically, what your argument does get is for each natural $n>1$ an **at-most-two-to-one** surjection $m^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow [0,1]$, and you need a further bit of argument to massage that to a bijection. *([Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) is useful here - note that it does not require the axiom of choice!)*

However, once you take that into account you will have a **correct** proof: it is indeed the case that $m^{\aleph_0}=n^{\aleph_0}$ whenever $1<m,n<\aleph_0$.

(In fact we can go even further since $2^{\aleph_0}=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}$, but that's a separate thing.)

Comment: If you know the Schröder-Bernstein theorem, then I think it's clearer to forget real numbers by finding an $i \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m$ embeds in $n^i$ and using that to embed $m^{\aleph_0}$ in $(n^i)^{\aleph_0} \simeq n^{\aleph_0}$ and similarly with $m$ and $n$ interchanged.